# How to use tailwindcss in nodejs

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Is there a way to use tailwindcss as a nodejs api like this

```js
const tailwind = require('tailwindcss')

const css = tailwind(html,css,....)
```

Comment: Interesting that this doesn't exist. Looks like the npm package only exports the postcss plugin but no API that provides similar features to the cli: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/src/index.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`postcss`](https://github.com/postcss/postcss) provides a [JS API](https://github.com/postcss/postcss#js-api) that can be combined with the [Tailwind postcss plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss):

```js
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')
const postcss = require('postcss')
const postcssNested = require('postcss-nested')
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('src/app.css', (err, css) => {
  postcss([autoprefixer, postcssNested, tailwindcss])
    .process(css, { from: 'src/app.css', to: 'dest/app.css' })
    .then(result => {
      fs.writeFile('dest/app.css', result.css, () => true)
      if ( result.map ) {
        fs.writeFile('dest/app.css.map', result.map.toString(), () => true)
      }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any. You can try using the CDN if it works for your use case.

```html
<script src="//cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```